# Play2 implicit Reads or Format for Json exception

Tags: json, scala, playframework

This is my Cout object:

```
case class Cout (idCout:Int, cout:String)

object Cout{

  implicit object CoutFormat extends Format[Cout] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): Cout = Cout(
      (json \ "idCout").as[Int],
      (json \ "cout").as[String]
    )

    def writes(s: Cout): JsValue = JsObject(Seq(
      "id" -> JsNumber(s.idCout),
      "cout" -> JsString(s.cout)
    ))
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use this class when calling a webservice using WS:

```
val cout = response.json.as[Cout]
```

But the scala compiler keeps complaining:

```
[RuntimeException: Int expected]
```

on the line `(json \ "idCout").as[Int],`

Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

- got the example from https://sites.google.com/site/play20zh/scala-developers/working-with-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `Format` instance: you're writing an `"id"` field but trying to read one named `"idCout"`. Change one of them:

```
case class Cout (idCout: Int, cout: String)

object Cout {
  implicit object CoutFormat extends Format[Cout] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): Cout = Cout(
      (json \ "idCout").as[Int],
      (json \ "cout").as[String]
    )

    def writes(s: Cout): JsValue = JsObject(Seq(
      "idCout" -> JsNumber(s.idCout),
      "cout" -> JsString(s.cout)
    ))
  }
}
```

And it works:

```
scala> Json.toJson(Cout(1, "test")).as[Cout]
res0: Cout = Cout(1,test)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the problem is still there.

Comment: The problem is coming from my json response. in fact what i get is `{"idCout":"1","cout":"test"}` and my class need an Int. i changed it to a String and it worked correctly. But still i don't know why the idCout is a String and not Int